# Unable to install modules in venv in pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm, conv-neural-network

I was unable to install few modules in my venv in pycharm community edition 2020.3
I had following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

above error is when i tried to install tensorflow,
I had same error when i tried to install keras,
Does Anyone knows what is wrong here
I am using latest pip and setuptools.

Comment: That error message seems strange. Can you provide more information how you tried to install the packages? Did you work from the console or with the PyCharm GUI?

Comment: Did you check whether your python version supports the tensorflow version you want to install?

Comment: I am using python 3.8.5 and i am trying to download tensorflow 2.4.0 I am using terminal in pycharm gui

Comment: What was the command you used to install tensorflow?

Comment: "pip install tensorflow" i tried "pip install tensorflow==2.4.0" too as well

Comment: Try installing other plethora of modules and which is your python version? As tensorflow doesn't support 3.10

Answer (score 1):

After creating `venv` environment in `Pycharm`, follow below steps to install `tensorflow`:

Go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> Press + button(bottom) 
-> Search '`tensorflow`' 
-> Specify version(right bottom) (check python 3.8.5 compatible `tensorflow` version in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu)) 
-> Select Install Package (left bottom)

Likewise, you can install other packages also in `Pycharm`.

You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/extras/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf) document for more details.